# iTunes says an update is available but iPhone doesn't (iOS 10.1.1)

Tags: ios, software-update, iphone

I recently updated my 6s Plus to iOS 10.1.1, and says it has the latest version. But when i connect it to iTunes both in mac & win it says an update available with the same version number.

should i upgrade or ignore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer from this MacRumors article: http://www.macrumors.com/2016/11/09/apple-releases-new-version-of-ios-10-1-1/

> Apple today seeded a minor version change to iOS 10.1.1, the current
>   version of the iOS 10 operating system. The update is minor enough
>   that it did not warrant a full 10.x.x number change, but it does
>   include an updated build number.
>
> iOS 10.1.1 being released today has a build number of 14B150, while
>   the initial iOS 10.1.1 release, which came on October 31, had a build
>   number of 14B100.
>
> **The new build of iOS 10.1.1 is only available as a download from
>   Apple's servers and cannot be obtained over-the-air at this time for
>   those who have already installed the first version of iOS 10.1.1.** The
>   new version of iOS 10.1.1 will likely be provided to those who have
>   yet to install iOS 10.1.1, as it otherwise requires an iTunes
>   connection to obtain.

In other words, you can safely update via iTunes to benefit from this minor update.

Comment: the update is 2.4+ GB, shouldn't it be like some MB's?

Comment: Major version changes of iOS often are 1-2+ GB in size, although Apple tried to cut it down with iOS 8 and 9. Minor updates are usually very small (100s of MB) but I've seen some updates in the beta channel that were last-number updates and were still 2 GB.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect there was a security patch made. Last year there was an update of a zero day exploit which was installed over the wires by link found in an email, with three unknown vulnerabilities.

Yesterday one of my banking apps said that my phone had been jailbroken - which I never did so I suspect that over the last few weeks a vulnerability has been found and must be updated via itunes only